# Name 'x' is not defined / Global variable?

Tags: python

I'm learning to program with python and I came across this issue: I'm trying to make a Guessing Game, and while trying to check for the win condition, the function doesn't recognise the input variable, which I made sure I returned with a previous function. So i get the 'name << 'first_input' is not defined' >> error. I thought it had something to do with the variable not being global or sth like that.

```
import random
ran_int = random.randint(1,100)
guesses = 0

# here you input the number and it keeps asking unless you do so with 1 to 100

def ask():
    first_input = 0
    while first_input < 1 or first_input > 100:
        first_input = int(input('Enter a number between 1 and 100: '))
    return first_input

# this is just to increment the number of guesses stored for showing at the end # of the game

def guesses_inc():
    global guesses
    guesses += 1
    return guesses

# here is where i get the error, as if my ask() function didn't return 
# the value properly or as if I assigned it wrongly

def check_win_1():
    if first_input == ran_int:
        guesses_inc()
        print(f'BINGO!\nYou guessed correctly after {guesses} times.')
    elif (abs(ran_int - first_input) <= 10):
        guesses_inc()
        print('WARM!')
        ask2()
    elif first_input < 1 or first_input > 100:
        print('Out of bounds!')
        ask2()
    else:
        guesses_inc()
        print('COLD!')
        ask2()

ask()
check_win_1()
```

And here is the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-bfd5497995df> in <module>
----> 1 check_win_1()

NameError: name 'first_input' is not defined
```

I didn't paste the whole code because while testing it it returned the error at this stage so I didn't think the rest mattered for this particular problem. I tried making the var input global and stuff like that but i don't think I did it properly.

Comment: You are probably missing parenthesis after `check_win_1` in the last line

Comment: your have not defined `ask2()` method as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method call is not correct. You should call your functions like this

```
def check_win_1(first_input):
    if first_input == ran_int:
        guesses_inc()
        print(f'BINGO!\nYou guessed correctly after {guesses} times.')
    elif (abs(ran_int - first_input) <= 10):
        guesses_inc()
        print('WARM!')
        ask2()
    elif first_input < 1 or first_input > 100:
        print('Out of bounds!')
        ask2()
    else:
        guesses_inc()
        print('COLD!')
        ask2()
first_input = ask()
check_win_1(first_input)
```

Comment: thanks! that worked perfectly! i wasn't storing the value returned by the function and not calling the proper arguments on the next one

Answer (score 0):

The error is there because you are trying to use `first_input` somewhere (i.e. inside `check_win_1()`).

A possible, not recommended, solution is to qualify your variable as `global`, which should be used **VERY** sparingly.

Instead, it is recommended to use function parameters, so as to encapsulate your code in self-contained blocks, e.g.:

```
def func(a, b):
    return a + b


x = func(10, 5)
```

rather than:

```
def func():
    global a, b
    return a + b

a = 10
b = 5

x = func()
```

---

For your that may mean doing something like:

```
def check_win_1(first_input, ran_int):
    ...
```

and use them accordingly, e.g.:

```
first_input = ask()
check_win_1(first_input, ran_int)
```

etc.

---

## EDIT

Following the above principle, your code could have looked like:

```
import random

MIN_VAL = 1
MAX_VAL = 100
WARM_LIMIT = 10


def ask_number(
        min_val=MIN_VAL,
        max_val=MAX_VAL):
    guess = None
    while guess is None:
        guess = int(input(f'Enter a number between {min_val} and {max_val}: '))
        if guess < min_val or guess > max_val:
            print('Out of bounds!')
            guess = None
    return guess


def check_guess(
        guess,
        target,
        num_guesses,
        warm_limit=WARM_LIMIT):
    if guess == target:
        print(f'BINGO!\nYou guessed correctly after {num_guesses} times.')
        return True
    else:
        if (abs(guess - target) <= warm_limit):
            print('WARM!')
        else:
            print('COLD!')
        return False


# : main
target = random.randint(MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL)
num_guesses = 0
won = False
while not won:
    guess = ask_number()
    num_guesses += 1
    won = check_guess(guess, target, num_guesses)
```